# How do I get smem to output useful results?

Tags: memory-usage

I recently installed [smem](http://www.selenic.com/smem/) on my ubuntu server with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install smem
```

It was installed correctly  without errors. But when I launch it I don't get any useful information about my processes...

```
$ smem
PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS
```

Just the column names. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I have Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the files in your system have a different format/naming or you use the -S argument but do not point to a ...`/proc`. If the SMAPS is not present in `/proc/$pid/` you'll also have nothing displayed.

smem requires `/proc/$pid/smaps`, `/proc/$pid/cmdline`, `/proc/$pid/stat`, `/proc/meminfo`, `/proc/version`.

You can find more info on /proc on the man pages of linux. e.g. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html.

There I found out that in order to have useful data, you need to have a 2.6.14 kernel at least and it needs to be compiled with the option `CONFIG_PROC_PAGE_MONITOR`.

Bernard

Comment: Useful information. But I have an Ubuntu 12.04 (server), and I have those files in the directories`/proc/$pid`.